# When preparing models for MS SQL Compact Edition why use native referenes and ID keys at the same time to associate objects/entities?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, associations

In learning ASP.NET, I follow this tutorial for ASP.NET MVC4: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4

Author prepares classes for creating database and putting its instances into this database. He defines for instance class Album:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models {
    public class Album {
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public Artist Artist { get; set; }  
    }
}
```

**Why do we have to keep redundant information about associations with other objects?** We got: `GenreId` and native reference `Genre`. What is the sense of it? As far as I know, relation database holds IDs and not references. So we should only keep IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the reference property is to allow Entity Framework to load the associated data for that reference, either explicitly or implicitly (lazy loading). With the reference property you can do:

```
album.Genre.Name;
```

To get the name of the genre (assuming it has a property called `Name`). However, without the reference, you would have to do something like:

```
var genre = context.Genres.Find(album.GenreId);
genre.Name;
```

However, the real power comes with the ability to combine queries. If you use reference properties and you fetch your album like:

```
context.Albums.Include("Genre").Find(albumId);
```

Then when you access a property like `album.Genre.Name`, no further queries are issued. Entity Framework did a join behind the scenes and loaded all the data at once. Whereas without the reference property, you would have to issue two queries to get here. This is even more powerful when you consider layers of reference properties. Assume for example that your `Artist` object also had a reference property to a class called `Tour`, and let's say each `Tour` has a collection navigation property to `Show`, which would be an individual shows on that tour. You could then do:

```
context.Albums.Include("Artist.Tours.Shows").Find(albumId);
```

And simultaneously query not only the album and artist, but all tours those artists have and all shows on each of those tours. Granted that's a large query, but it's a *single* query -- that's the important part. Without those reference properties you would have to do something like:

```
var album = context.Albums.Find(albumId); // 1 query
var artist = context.Artists.Find(album.ArtistId); // 1 query
var tours = context.Tours.Where(m => m.ArtistId == artist.Id); // 1  query
foreach (var tour in tours)
{
    var shows = context.Shows.Where(m => m.TourId == tour.Id); // N queries
    foreach (var show in shows)
    {
        // do something with show
    }
}
```

You're now issuing a *ton* of queries to get that data you need, whereas you could have just used one with the reference properties.